# org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1

Tags: android, charts

I am getting this error:

> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
>       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
>   Required by:
>       project :[hellocharts-libraryNew](https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while running my app for first time on newly installed android studio. I checked the

> Tools Menu->SDK Manager->Android Studio ->Enable Embedded Maven repository checkBox.[image]

Now it will resolved the error! Try it out!